# Is there a way to stay in the command line window after executing a line?

Tags: command-line, command-line-window

I find the command-line window incredibly useful for experimenting with my vim environment. But it's annoying to have to type `q:` every time I execute a line with `<CR>`. Is there a way to execute the line under my cursor *but not exit the command line window*?

The help menu doesn't seem to suggest that. Only how to get out of the command line window.

Comment: You could have a mapping do `<CR>q:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
nnoremap <CR> <CR>q:
```

This mapping needs to be active only in the command-line window, so,

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>q:
```

Place in your vimrc, preferably surrounded by an `augroup/au!` definition.